# php code help needed for this ssnippet

Tags: php, html

```
    <li>
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?=$this->baseUrl?>/trip/edittrip/<?php echo $this->tripdes[0]['Id']; ?>"
        <?php if($this->trip==active) { ?> class="act" <?php } ?>>General Info</a>
    </li>
```

When I am debugging it, i am getting an error that: start tag () not closed properly, expected '>'

I am new to html and php and can't identify the reason behind this message although this code was working fine earlier. Can somebody plz help me over here?

Comment: I don't see any problem here (as long as short tags are supported). How are you debugging it?

Comment: I am using eclipse PDT (because of zend framework support). This is an old application I got developed from somebody and now trying to make it work

Comment: This is a problem with your program then. There is nothing wrong with the code, probably what is happening is that your program parser is getting confused by something here.

Comment: @AnkurBansal. I have provide with an Explanation & Solution about your request. Have a look and share thought. if you face any hindrance let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li>
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?=$this->baseUrl?>/trip/edittrip/<?php echo $this->tripdes[0]['Id']; ?>">
    <?php if($this->trip==active) { ?> class="act" <?php } ?>General Info</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this code and apparently the error went away but I am not sure if the output is there yet since there are many such instances which I need to correct before I am sure. Will keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:** You are mixing up the syntax of the `PHP tags`.

In PHP you have tags for open and close in two methods. You have to use any one of them.

1. `<?php //Code Here ?>` - First Method
2. `<?= //Code Here ?>` - Second Method

It is advisable to use any one format for the Code.

**Error Highlights:**

**Question:**

> You need to add the `class="act"` when the `IF` is **TRUE** or else you no need to add the class if the condition FAILS.

**Answer:**

When you are checking the IF condition over to the code you need to use `ECHO` for printing some value over ti the HTML otherwise it will not print the code what you have written inside the code.

> **Important:** You need to add the class before the closing of the `<a>` tag. If you echo the tag outside the code will lead in error.

The IF part will look like this.

```
<?php if($this->trip==active) { echo 'class="act"'; } else{} ?>
```

Hence you code will look like as follows.

```
<li>
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/trip/edittrip/<?php echo $this->tripdes[0]['Id']; ?>"<?php if($this->trip==active) { echo 'class="act"'; } else{} ?>>General Info</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for the detailed solution. I have used your code but it still gives me the same error message. Is this an issue with my debugger? I can try to use another debugger if you can recommend me one.